# Having issues with returning data on MongoDB find

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have this code that get all the user in database and for every user a post (which mean what user is publishing) is selected the problem that I don't get any error but also I don't get any result I don't Know why

this my code

```
 User.find({}).lean(true).exec((err, users) => {
            var userMap = [];
            for (let i =0 ; i < users.length; i++) { 
                console.log('Im here')

                    if(users[i].posts.length) {
                        console.log(users[i])
                        for (let j = 0; j < users[i].posts.length; j++) {
                        console.log('Im here 2')
                        userMap.push({ user: users[i], posts: users[i].posts[j] });
                        console.log('Im here 3')
                    }    
        }

        }
        console.log(userMap);
```

the error for this code is below : 
[image]
the Only result that I get for `console.log(userMap)` is `[]` and `console.log(users.length) => undefined`

Any ideas please,

Best Regards,

[

Comment: Typo here :: `for (let i; i < users.length; i++) {` you need to have `let i : 0` & also I don't think you need those for loops to do this, can you post sample docs & required o/p from DB..

Comment: @whoami thank you for the typo but what I'm trying to do is when a user  go to homePage he will see all the posts made by the other users, if you got something feel free to post it  :D ,,, the error now `users is not defined` line `for (let i=0 ; i < users.length; i++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues with your code, try below code :

```
User.find({}).lean(true).exec((err, users) => {
    var userMap = [];
    for (let i =0 ; i < users.length; i++) { 
        console.log('Im here')
        for (let j = 0; j < users[i].posts.length; j++) {
            console.log('Im here 2')
            userMap.push({ user: users[i], posts: users[i].posts[j] });
            console.log('Im here 3')
    }

}
console.log(userMap);
```

**Issues :** Typo at `let i` needs to be `let i =0` & also you need to use `.lean(true)` to convert MongoDB BSON document to .Js object inorder to access it & operate on it.

Comment: it looped once but the second one I get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` at this line `for (let j = 0; j < users[i].posts.length; j++) ` and for `console.log(userMap)` it is not reached yet

Comment: @Nodegeek : That means for that particular user there are no posts !! prior to `for (let j = 0; j < users[i].posts.length; j++) {` you can have an `if` check like  `if(users[i].posts.length)` & in the else push `[]` to posts for that user..

Comment: @Nodegeek : Do you mean to say  avoid user which has got no posts from being added to `userMap`?

Comment: @Nodegeek : Ok wrap `for (let j = 0; j < users[i].posts.length; j++) {....}` inside `if(users[i].posts.length){...here...}`...

Comment: this is what I get https://ibb.co/yYYBrzQ
https://ibb.co/VLGxtbC

Comment: @Nodegeek : Please post the latest code along with what you're getting in `users`

Comment: @Nodegeek : I've asked you to put for loop inside if condition !! Try to bring `for(let j=0.....){...}` inside of `if(users[i].posts && users[i].posts.length)` & everything should work as expected...

Comment: @Nodegeek : check my previous comment try to update if block(it differs to what I’ve given) and give it a try

Comment: Thank you it worked I'm so tired I didn't see that I didn't get the `users[i].posts.length`